# Java style guide, why should you do single class imports?

Tags: java, coding-style

In [Google's Java style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s3.3.1-wildcard-imports) they suggest to always use Single class imports, but they don't give a reason. What are the reasons to adopt this style of importing single classes instead of `*`?

Also, side question, how to I set up IntelliJ to optimize my imports in this fashion?

Comment: Polluting your namespace reduces the number of names you can use locally without confusion.  The last two words of that sentence are the most important part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing all the classes in a package increases the probability of name clash.

That said, nowadays IDEs can write the imports for you.